# Cyrillic export from Excel to CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel, export, unicode, csv, character-encoding

I have an application where I upload some content in CSV format, however the main document where I have my data is an Excel document.

I use *Save As » CSV* in order to make a CSV file, but it is not going to save the cyrillic values, instead the text looks like question marks (the system does not let me paste a lot of question marks here).

How do I export it correctly?

Comment: What version of excel?

Comment: Microsoft Excel 2010

Answer (score 1):

In this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/638389/excel-2007-doesnt-preserve-asian-characters-when-converting-to-csv?rq=1), you will find Excel indeed does not preserve unicode characters when saving as csv. Their solution is to save as unicode tab separated text

To save with Unicode encoding in Excel,

Save as, choose text, then next to the save button, you see "tools" menu. 
Choose web options, 
then encoding tab, 
then select the encoding you like. 
I would suggest to save everything in UTF8, but that is your choice. 
Note this is in Excel 2007 or above.

Answer (score 1):

Excel does not support Unicode encoding when saving as CSV. You can copy your table to a program that does (e.g. Google Sheets) and then export it to CSV in that program.

Answer (score 0):

do you use correct encoding? I use Libreoffice Calc and there you have to specify output encoding for the CSV or DBF file (and there should be something similar also in Excel). I used this also with some Japanese datasets and it looked OK. I assume that you should use UTF-8 in your case.

Comment: Actually my Excel is saving CSV in ANSI and not UTF8 or Unicode and I do not know how can I change that.

Comment: I also checked this but with no result http://superuser.com/questions/170926/saving-a-file-in-a-csv-type-in-excel-always-removes-the-bom